# Riemann integrability of absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

***Prove using the definition of Riemann integrability that the function $f : [−2, 2] → \mathbb{R}$, $x → |x|$,
is integrable.***

Im pretty stuck with this. I know the definition that "A bounded function $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such, that $U_P − L_p < \epsilon.$"

However i cannot come up with a way to get the partition in terms of $\epsilon$ or $n$ so that i could proceed with the rest. How should i go about this?

Comment: What happens if you make sure that $0$ is one of your partition points?

Comment: Well i could go with $\frac{2-(-2)}{4} = 1$ so i would get $P = (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)$, but that doens't seem to help me since i need the partition to be in terms of $\epsilon$ or $n$ right?

Answer (score 0):

Divide your interval into $n$ equal parts of length $\frac {4}{n}$

Note that on each subinteval of length $\frac {4}{n}$ the difference between the maxium and the minimum of your function is $\frac {4}{n}$

Thus  $$U(f,P)-L(f,P)\le \frac {4}{n} \times 4 = \frac {16}{n}$$

Given an $\epsilon >0$, you let $n>\frac {16}{\epsilon}$ and go from there.

Comment: I think you'd better make sure $n$ is even.

Comment: Could you explain how did you come up with $\frac{4}{n}$?

Comment: The slope of your function is either $1$ or $-1$ so on a subinterval of length $4/n$ the maximum variation is $4/n$